# Umbraco 7 add new Item to Dashboard

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to add new "Section" Item to Umbraco 7. Without Success.

What I am trying to achieve is to Have additional Icon in left side menu after members icon.
I saw , google analytics package adding icon there after installation.

[image]

I've tried to change dashboard.config , application.config , without success. Can anyone point to me to some tutorial on how to do it , googling the subj , didn't brought results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Markus has some good tips but his blog was written for 7.0 - some things have changed in 7.1. Work through Tim Geyssens's blog posts http://www.nibble.be/?p=434 http://www.nibble.be/?p=440

One very important tip - remember to add the section to the users login account! You might have done everything right and missed adding your custom section to your user account!

Comment: your tip was the solution to the problem :) ! Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you "add your custom section to your user account". I've added a package but can't see my dashboard anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Markus Johansson runs through the process on his blog, [here](http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/11/22/creating-custom-sections-in-umbraco-7-part-1.aspx).

Comment: As above - this was written for 7.0 so there are some changes since.. I'd start with the Tim Geyssens blog.